# Prevent Julia from writing to console when instantiating large arrays

Tags: console, read-eval-print-loop, julia

Is there a command that will prevent Julia from printing out all of the values in an array when I create it? This can be annoying when creating large arrays in the REPL. For example when I run this:

```
julia> bigArray = Array[ [1:1000000], [1:1000000] ]
```

I would rather it not print all of the values to the console. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think this should be considered a bug in Julia. For simpler structures, we limit the printing automatically. There are many open issues to make recursive array printing more robust, but there are more fundamental issues that need to be resolved first.

Comment: That was part of why I was confused. Small arrays would only print a few values but when I created "large" arrays it would print the whole thing. As long as there's a way to prevent the output I can work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a semicolon

```
julia> bigArray = Array[ [1:1000000], [1:1000000] ];
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something incredibly simple.